# How to create patch from diff of two patch set in gerrit

Tags: diff, gerrit, generate

There can be multiple patch-set in a given gerrit commit. Is it possible to create diff.patch from the difference of two specific patch-set of this same commit?

I need this because I made changes on top of patch-set 3 and by the time I pushed my changes patch-set 4 was already in. Now my changes are part of patch-set 5 and patch-set 4 changes are lost. Currently I am manually identifying changes and fixing :(

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do this using the Gerrit UI. For example use the below link to examine the change: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/c/gerrit/+/253332/4..5

Select a different patch set:

[image]

You can select the patch sets you would like to compare in the drop down box.

[image]

Alternatively, if you prefer to do this from the command line you can download the individual patchsets and do a diff. Below I create branches with names to represent the patch sets. However, you can also run the diff using the SHA-1 of the patchsets.

```
git fetch "https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit" refs/changes/32/253332/4 && git branch b253332-4 FETCH_HEAD
git fetch "https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit" refs/changes/32/253332/5 && git branch b253332-5 FETCH_HEAD
git diff  b253332-4..b253332-5
```